# Proper way to terminate a process in python when it may lock resources

Tags: python, multiprocessing, locking, terminate

I use simple method from mans:

```
process_one.start()

# process work here and may call lock, and when it locked some resources
# we call terminate, is it ok? 

process_one.terminate() 
process_one.join()
```

I am afraid if use that scheme it may lock program. For example if **process_one** will call another processes and threads inside.

Do you know a way to terminate it properly: with "sub"processes and even when it lock some res inside subprocesses ant subthreads?

Comment: get pid and kill -9 ?

Comment: @vks and by that all possible locks will kill too?